# Getting a nil in Swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I am creating an app where I have annotation view showing that when you click it shows on the `DetailsViewController` that annotation data. However, I get "Name", and "Address" data but for phone Number I am getting set as `nil`. So, if you guys can see my code & help me solve it, I will be appreciated it.

Here is my code:

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

protocol UserLocationDelegate {
  func userLocation(latitude :Double, longitude :Double)
}

class NearMeMapViewController: ARViewController, ARDataSource, MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

  var nearMeIndexSelected = NearMeIndexTitle ()
  var locationManager : CLLocationManager!
  var nearMeARAnnotations = [ARAnnotation]()


  var nearMeRequests = [NearMeRequest]()
  var delegate : UserLocationDelegate!



  var place: Place?



  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    self.title = nearMeIndexSelected.indexTitle


    self.locationManager = CLLocationManager ()
    self.locationManager.delegate = self
    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    self.locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLHeadingFilterNone
    self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

    self.dataSource = self
    self.headingSmoothingFactor = 0.05
    self.maxVisibleAnnotations = 30

    getNearMeIndexSelectedLocation()



  }

  func getNearMeIndexSelectedLocation()

    {

    let nearMeRequest = MKLocalSearchRequest()
    nearMeRequest.naturalLanguageQuery = nearMeIndexSelected.indexTitle
    let nearMeregion = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(self.locationManager.location!.coordinate, 250, 250)
    nearMeRequest.region = nearMeregion
    let nearMeSearch = MKLocalSearch(request: nearMeRequest)
    nearMeSearch.start { (response : MKLocalSearchResponse?, error :Error?) in

      for requestItem in (response?.mapItems)! {

        let nearMeIndexRequest = NearMeRequest ()
        nearMeIndexRequest.name = requestItem.name
        nearMeIndexRequest.coordinate = requestItem.placemark.coordinate
        nearMeIndexRequest.address = requestItem.placemark.addressDictionary?["FormattedAddressLines"] as! [String]
        nearMeIndexRequest.street = requestItem.placemark.addressDictionary?["Street"] as! String!
        nearMeIndexRequest.city = requestItem.placemark.addressDictionary?["City"] as! String
        nearMeIndexRequest.state = requestItem.placemark.addressDictionary?["State"] as! String
        nearMeIndexRequest.zip = requestItem.placemark.addressDictionary?["ZIP"] as! String

        self.nearMeRequests.append(nearMeIndexRequest)
        print(requestItem.placemark.name)

      }

      for nearMe in self.nearMeRequests {


        let annotation = NearMeAnnotation(nearMeRequest: nearMe)

        self.nearMeARAnnotations.append(annotation)
        self.setAnnotations(self.nearMeARAnnotations)




      }

    }

  }




  func ar(_ arViewController: ARViewController, viewForAnnotation: ARAnnotation) -> ARAnnotationView {

    let annotationView = NearMeARAnnotationView(annotation: viewForAnnotation)

    //  annotationView.delegate = self
    annotationView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 150, height: 50)
     let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.tapBlurButton(_:)))
    annotationView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
    return annotationView

  }



  func tapBlurButton(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {



    if let annotationView = sender.view as? NearMeARAnnotationView {
      if let detailsVc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DetailsViewController")
        as? DetailsViewController {
        detailsVc.annotation = annotationView.annotation
          if let annotation = annotationView.annotation as? Place {
      detailsVc.place = annotation

    }




        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(detailsVc, animated: true)

      }
    }
  }


}
```

Comment: hey Robert, thats a lot of code to comb through. my experience tells me that you won't get an answer until you display only the code which is relevant to the issue

Comment: which position crash?

Comment: Just put relevant code only so others will not be confused as like you :)

Comment: @Robert and you can check this issue with breakpoints.

Comment: Check updated question, guys. I have comment on my first block of code that I believe thats the problem that causes that not printing the phone number of a annotation view.

Comment: I have updated my question once more when I do `if let annotation = annotationView.annotation as? Place {
          detailsVc.place = annotation`  I get the place is `nil` which in my `DetailsViewController` I have it declared as `var place: Place!`

Comment: `detailsVc.place = annotation` is actually called?

Answer (score 1):

Just looking over your code quickly:

```
"\(nearMeAnnotation.nearMeRequest.phone)"
```

All the other ones have a forced unwrap, this one doesn't. Most probably the value is `nil` and since you ask for a string representation of a wrapped `var` that might really be `nil` sometimes.

I think you should use a default value everywhere instead of a forced unwrap, like:

```
"\(nearMeAnnotation.nearMeRequest.phone ?? "")"
```

but also:

```
"\(nearMeAnnotation.nearMeRequest.street ?? "") \(nearMeAnnotation.nearMeRequest.state ?? "") \(nearMeAnnotation.nearMeRequest.state ?? "") \(nearMeAnnotation.nearMeRequest.zip ?? "")"
```

With forced unwraps your application will crash if a certain value is not set. This could be handled more elegantly if they're really required, for example already in the constructor of your object. There's the root cause of the optionals you're seeing. In this case `NearMeAnnotation`.

Comment: Please post the contents of `NearMeAnnotation` as the problem is related to the type you declare in that class. In general you should never use force-unwrapping except perhaps for `IBOutlet`s. Nor declare something like `var myString: String!`

Comment: @Robert You set it to `unknown` yourself in `tableView:cellForRowAt indexPath:`. What do you expect otherwise?

Comment: @Robert why are you editing my answer? it's blocking you from accepting it as it is?